# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'abc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstack, rhel7, devstack

I'm trying to install devstack in my RHEL 7 VM. Earlier everything went good. But while installing the nova, its throwing the following error. How can i resolve this. Should i need to change the code in all the trace back files or any python package/module is available which can resolve this issue? I don't think it's a good idea to change the code in the mentioned files. Is there any way to proceed further.(The python version is 2.7)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/nova-manage", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1725, in main
config.parse_args(sys.argv)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/config.py", line 55, in parse_args
rpc.init(CONF)
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/rpc.py", line 63, in init
TRANSPORT = create_transport(get_transport_url())
File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/rpc.py", line 172, in get_transport_url
return messaging.TransportURL.parse(CONF, url_str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debtcollector/removals.py", line 261, 
in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 
558, in parse
port = int(port)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

Comment: How are you starting this program?  It looks like it expects a port as a command line argument and you're giving it `"abc"`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  By executing the binary stack.sh . Actually my company name is coming in place of abc. To keep it confidential i replaced it with "abc". Assuming both to be string.

Comment: `.sh` files are shell files, so you should be able to open it and read it as text.  Are you providing any command line arguments when you invoke that command?  If you aren't telling the command the name of your company, it's probable that someone at your company wrote that file.  If possible you should talk to them

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Actually the entire software of devstack is available in the git. Only the configuration file (local.conf) is created by me. Is the error only related to that last trace back file (i.e., transport.py) or with all files.